# ng2-datepicker 2.1.6 not working with angular 2.4.0

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, angular2-routing, ng2-datepicker

I was using `ng2-datepicker`:

```
"ng2-datepicker": "^1.8.3",
```

That is compatible with my angular project but that plugin does not have `minYear` and `maxYear` options, that's why I need to update `datePicker` plugin to

```
 "ng2-datepicker": "^2.1.6",
```

but it is showing error to my projects

Error:

> `DatePickerModule` is not export member of ng `ng2-datepicker`
>
> `DatePickerOptions` is not export member of ng `ng2-datepicker`

I added `NgDatepickerModule` but it also not compatible with my project.

Comment: If you are open to choose any other library. I would say to go with ngx-mydatepicker.
Have a look at here - https://kekeh.github.io/ngx-mydatepicker/

Comment: There is bug in version of  1.8.3